# HasMany with belongsToMany relationship

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models: `Persons`, `Events` and `Files`. A `Persons` can have many `Events` and many `Events` can have many `Files`.

```
| persons |
-----------
id
name


| events |
----------
id
person_id
name


| event_file |
--------------
id
event_id
file_id


| files |
---------
id
name
```

In the `Persons` model I have this relationship:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Events', 'person_id');
}
```

In the `Events` model:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Files', 'event_file', 'event_id', 'file_id');
}
```

Is it possible to create a relation directly between `Persons` and `Files` that translates to something like:

```
$files = Person::find($id)->events->files;
// OR
$files = Person::find($id)->files;
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible with builtin methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the comment, it's impossible to setup such relationship with builtin methods of Eloquent. Here's how you can get the `files` using a bit of trickery:

```
Person::with(['events.files' => function ($q) use (&$files) {
  $files = $q->get()->unique();
}])->find($id);
```

Then:

```
$files; // collection of files related to the Person through collection of his events
```

Mind that this code will run additional query to get the files, so in the example above:

```
1 fetch Person
2 fetch Events related to Person
3 fetch Files related to all the Events
4 again fetch Files related to all the Events
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "hasManyThrough".
On the example bellow, you could see that i want to get the posts, through the users. Just like you want to get files through events.

```
class Country extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User');
    }

}
```

And you would invoke as:

```
$country->posts;
```

Or, as you wish:

```
Person:find(1)->files;
```

If you want a better explanation, follow the link to Laravel's own page:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through

Comment: No, `hasManyThrough` doesn't work with `belongsToMany`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what's your point. It's not "with", It's replacing. There's a problem using like that? I can't test it right now.

Comment: Yes, it won't work with relations other than cascading, ie. `A hasMany B, B hasMany C`. I'm not talking about `with` method at all.

Comment: Oh, sorry about misleading you. Not talking about "with" method, just about with belongsToMany. I just tought about what he's asking, and, I'm really wrong. I'm just giving him, the files, through events, but not the events.

Comment: Klaus, you didn't get my point. You can't do what you suggested. Try it and you will know what I'm talking about.

Comment: I get it. There is the relation between events, event_file, files. Cause of that, my answer is totally incorrect. Can't go through it. I can't test any code right now, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Person::where('id',$id)->with('events')->with('events.files')->get();
```

? eagerload that